# InvalidCastException was unhandled in datagridview

Tags: c#

My program stops whenever I press the blank row of the `DataGridView` in my form. The error says:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled.

This is the part of the code where the error is happening:

```
private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value); //This is the line with the error
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString();
    textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is the problem occurring when you start application or when you click the dataGridView?  It is either due to the cell not being a number, being null, no rows selected.  You could try "int? id" to handle case when null.  You may also get into the method during the construction of the form and may need to ignore click when datatGridView1.Rows.Count  <= 0;

Comment: the error shows up whenever i click the blank row of the `DataGridView`, Probably thats the last row. The `id` variable has an `int` datatype. @jdweng

Comment: As I said you can make the variable type int? so Convert.ToInt32 doesn't give error, or test doe dataGridView1.SelectedCells == null, or dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0] == null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've just said:

> program stop whenever i press the blank row

and then you've got

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value); //This is the line with the error
```

It will always fail, because `Int` is value type and cannot be null, and when you've got empty row the value on this cell will be most likely `null`.

Try something like this:

```
try
{
    id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value); //This is the line with the error
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString();
    textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[4].Value.ToString();
}
catch(InvalidCastException exception)
{
    // not much to do with it, you can display assign empty valuest to your text boxes or notify user that there's nothing to select
}
```

Alternate apporach could be checking if the cell has value.

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value))
{
    return;
}

id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value); 
//Assign values to textboxes
```

And there's also another possibility:

```
int id;
if(int.TryParse( dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString(), out id ))
{
    //Assign values to textboxes
}
```

Comment: The first solution you made has an error: `A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Comment: Right, your EventArgs parameter is declared as `e`. I'll update this.

Comment: and the second still has a InvalidCastException was unhandled. the 3rd has 2 errors though im still trying to fix it.. well lets just say it ended up bad :) @yoger

Comment: You can try second one now. If your type on that cell is `string` then it's possible that it's not null, just empty. Have you checked what's actual value on that cell?
And since you work with selection it would be better to rely on event `dataGridView1.SelectionChanged` than `dataGridView1.Click`.

Comment: Your update 1st solution worked! much obliged bro :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of first grid cell?

The variable you are trying to convert is non-numerical or some special character datatype, and that is why it is causing an error. I suggest you to use the `convert.toString()` method if you want to use non-numerical or a combination of non-numerical and numerical data.

Comment: im using an `int` datatype for `id`. the value the program passes to the `id` variable is an auto incriment numbers... cuz im using it for the numbering system of my database. @mBangali